# Should an Angularjs 1 factory return an instantiated object or a constructor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a factory in Angular 1 that I want to use to create a new instance of in the consuming code.
So the question is should the factory return a function that returns a new instance of the object or should I just return the constructor function... and why?

Option 1, Creation Function:

```
    module.factory('MyObject', function(){

        function MyObject(args){
            stuff...
        }

        return {
            create: function (args) {
                return new MyObject(args);
            }
        }
    })
```

Can then be instantiated doing

```
var thing = MyObject.create(args);
```

Option 2, Return Constructor Function :

```
    module.factory('MyObject', function(){

        function MyObject(args){
            stuff...
        }

        return MyObject;
    })
```

Can then be instantiated doing

```
var thing = new MyObject(args);
```

Comment: Amgular is doing the 'new' on your MyObject.  It is guaranteed to be a singleton.  You should return a constructor function.

Comment: @Stevo you wanted to re-instantiate class whenever you ask for service?

Comment: @brewsky I'm looking for a more detailed answer. I understand that the provider is a singleton, but there is a subtlety of difference between the two scenarios I need to understand.

Comment: @PankajParkar I want to do what I would do if I wasn't working in Angular. I want to be able to create objects 'MyObject' based upon the Prototype I have created. But I want to create those in my other services and controllers etc. So I would inject the MyObject in other places in my app, but should the injected service be the object literal with a create function that returns a new object, or simply return the constructor function and let the consuming code instantiate the object (using new MyObject). What's the difference? Is there any?

Comment: @Stevo I see what you want. I think both options looks similar to me.. out which 1st one look bit smarter which is instantiated & returning prototype object when you ask for it..

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks - but I want more than opinion. I want to know if there are definite reasons for one over the other.

Comment: The technical reason to use 'new' in javascript is if your object is using prototypical inheritance.  Then you must 'new' up the object otherwise your method in the proto chain may not be called.   Another reason if you had instance data associated with the object, you should new up every instance and not use the singleton pattern.   I suspect that  your question isn't about Angular but about Javascript.  In Javascript if you are doing prototypical inheritance, you must do a 'new'.  Otherwise, just use the constructor function.

Comment: @Stevo - After re-reading your response, I think what you need is to use a factory design pattern as your Angular service.  And in your service, you  will have 1 method 'create' which returns a 'new' instance of your object.

Comment: @brewsky yup, and my question is why is that method preferred over returning the constructor function and letting the consumer create the object via the new operator? I don't see a difference. Does it matter? If so, why?

Comment: It is the factory design pattern and the responsibility for creating the objects is done in a single location.  I don't know your code but what if in six months you forget 'new' up the object, will your code still work then?  There are a lot of what-if'

Comment: Found this relating to my conundrum: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e#.gtqg08atr. Thanks Eric :)