# Should an AngularJS factory to return a function (class) or an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

If I want an Angular JS factory that is used to create multiple "widgets", which is the best method to follow?

Starting with this basic framework...

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('widgetFactory', widgetFactory);

function widgetFactory() {
    /* { Option A or B goes here } */
}
```

...there seem to be two options that are roughly equivalent:

**A** - *return an object with a create function*

```
return {
    createWidget: createWidget
};
function createwidget(options) {
    return new Widget(options);
}
function Widget (options) { // the class
    this.name = options.name;
    /* etc. */
}
```

and then use it in the controller like: `var w = widgetFactory.createWidget(options);`

...or... **B** - *return a function (acting as a class)*

```
return Widget;
function Widget (options) { // the class
    this.name = options.name;
    /* etc. */
}
```

and then use it in the controller like: `var w = new widgetFactory(options);`

[Style guides like this one](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#factories) seem to point to "A" being preferred, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: if you want a class...probably would use a service not factory. Do a search for "angular service vs factory"...lots of info on web

Comment: That might be good advice but I'm attempting to keep with this style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#services -- which says "Since these [services] are so similar to factories, use a factory instead for consistency."

Comment: excellent resource...have used it a lot myself. Personally I would use your `A` but that is really all about personal preference and your own code style

Comment: I'm leaning towards A myself -- only because it will be easier to stick with a standard of: *all factories return an object*. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305012/should-an-angularjs-1-factory-return-an-instantiated-object-or-a-constructor

Comment: also easier to add things that aren't really part of Widget to it if needed